# Increment a record's score when user clicks "vote" w/php & mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, math

I'm creating a jokes website. Each joke is stored as a record in mysql db. I'm trying to develop a vote link which increments the joke record's "score" column when a "vote" link is clicked.

I'm just hoping for some general direction as to how to do this... I'm planning on using jquery's ajax to send the joke's id to a php page to process. I'm just not sure how exactly to process it... something like this?

```
 $id = $_POST['id']
 mysql_query("UPDATE jokes SET score='++' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Each joke will be within a uniquely identified `<div>` (the id= is generated with the record's unique id).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Remember to sanitize your database inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/) use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per "The Scrum Meister"'s suggestion

```
mysql_query("UPDATE jokes SET score= score + 1 WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE jokes SET score= score + 1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: As suggested by "The Scrum Meister " , If you dont sanitize your db inputs , your open to sql injection